# iOS: make "Location" appear in the app settings without requesting for location authorization (Tile app example)

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, ibeacon, ios13

## Long story short:

I'd like to make "Location" appear in the app settings without requesting for location authorization, like the Tile app does.

[image: Image: Tile has Location in the app settings without requesting for location authorization]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install the Tile app.

   - There is no "Location" in the app settings.
2. Open the app, accept Bluetooth access request (does it matter?).

   - There is still no "Location" in the app settings, but Bluetooth appears.
3. Use the app for about 20 seconds (can't be shorter).

   - "Location" appears in the app settings - how?

This is presented on the video below:

https://media.giphy.com/media/h5dPQPbBHzEhdLTrKz/giphy.gif

How can I achieve this?

---

## Background - why

Since iOS 13, the user cannot be asked for `Always` location authorization directly. When the developer requests for `Always` authorization, the user can select only `While in Use` option and the app gets `Provisional Always` authorization. Until the user is prompted again (iOS decides when), the user will see `While in Use` authorization in the app settings.

Which means:

- `Always` --> `CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways` and `Always` in the app settings.
- `Provisional Always` --> also `CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways` but `While in Use` in the app settings.

This is well described in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57973466/1570496).

[The problem is that the application cannot read the location in the background without `Always` authorization](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/705/?time=480) (it can, but only for 5-10 seconds), which greatly limits the main functionality of some apps (e.g. iBeacon trackers).

A well-known practice is to check if the app has `Always` authorization, and if not, present information describing why this is important and how the user can change it (manually in settings).

But we cannot distinguish if we have `Always` or `Provisional Always` authorization status ([at least directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689312/ios-13-check-for-provisional-authorization-status-of-cllocationmanager)), so the logic:

```
if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorizedAlways) {
    // Prompt the user to change Location access to Always manually in settings
}
```

will not work for `Provisional Always` authorization status.

The solution could be to ask the user to choose `Always` manually in the settings **before requesting location authorization**, to prevent `Provisional Always` state from happening. I thought it was impossible without calling `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` first, but Tile somehow does it, as presented on the previous video.

## Update:

I already have:

- `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription`
- `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`
- `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`

privacy keys set in Info.plist file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reveal "Location" in the app settings without asking for permission first (`Always` requires two-step opt-in), you need to call `locationManager.requestLocation()`.

```
func scheduleLocationUpdates() {
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() && CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        // hide full screen instruction (if shown)
    } else {
        if (UIDevice.current.systemVersion as NSString).floatValue >= 13.0 {
            locationManager.requestLocation() // reveal "Location" in app settings (works on iOS 13 only)
            // show full screen instruction how to provide "Always authorization"
        } else {
            if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
                locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            } else {
                // show full screen instruction how to provide "Always authorization"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Function `scheduleLocationUpdates()` should called in `viewWillAppear` and after `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification` event (e.g. when the user comes back from Settings).

**On iOS 12 "Location" will not appear in the app settings without asking for the permission first.** But you can ask for `Always` permission directly (without two steps), so this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply putting the `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in your plist and then instantiating a `CLLocationServices` instance and using it to try to start a location update?  I suspect this will cause the entry to appear in settings even if the location update will not function until permission is granted.

Comment: Yes, I had the keys, but starting location updates **without** asking for permission helped. Thank you! Although I'm a bit worried it may stop working after some iOS update, it doesn't sound like a feature.

Comment: It's always possible Apple could make a future change here (Apple often surprises us!), but I think it is reasonably safe to use this technique, because I believe it is consistent with the way Apple wants their permission system to work -- only if an app tries to use location does the permission setting show up.  Just my two cents.

Comment: ***This works on iOS13 only.*** That's the risk of using undocumented behaviours...